# Float and list-style-position: inside, not working in latest chrome?

Tags: css, html

I just got an email from a client and a few list element on his site have broken over night?
I have not changed any code in the last months and when i try this simple code: Firefox and IE do respect the list-style-position: inside; on floated lists elements, but now Chrome dose not?! Are there a fix? Is this a bug or a new standard? (Html5 DTD)

[My Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2bMPf/1/)

```
<style>    
ul {
    list-style-position: inside;
    width:150px;
}

li {
    background:#c9c9c9;
    float:left;
    clear:both;
}
</style>


<div class="wrapper">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Product1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Product2</a></li>
    </ul>
    <div class="clear"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it's a bug.
Check [this page](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=278115).

Comment: It appears as though this issue has been resolved in Chrome but still affects Firefox.. http://stackoverflow.com/a/25778241/1922144

Comment: Just noting that, for a CSS layman like me, list-style-position inside is absolutely evil: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=36854. Avoid if you can.

Answer (score 1):

It seems to be a bug in Chrome. U may try using the following code for serving the purpose

```
ul li{
margin-left:1em;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
.clear{clear:both;}
li {
    background:#c9c9c9;
    clear:both;
    list-style-position: inside;
}
ul {
    width:150px;
}
```

check this in your jsfiddle