# aligning li items in the same line

Tags: css, html

I am trying to have li items in the same line. I managed to get that but for some reason each li item gets broken in 2 lines. I am not sure why. Is there a way I can fix it?

HTML:

```
<section class="carousel price_carousel">   <!--Price section -->
<div class="wrapper" >
  <ul  class="list">
    <li>TEXT TEXT </li>
    <li>TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT</li>
    <li>TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT</li>
 </ul>
 </div>
```

JSfiddle(with CSS) : http://jsfiddle.net/bgeswkr4/

Comment: Are you looking for `white-space: nowrap`? http://jsfiddle.net/gu2em2ex/ ( This assumes they are `inline` elements..).

Comment: Now they do remain in the same line but the bulllet points are disappearing.

Comment: @user3861559 You could add it via a pseudo element - http://jsfiddle.net/13zeew3t/

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/techsin/9dq33bov/

Comment: today i relearned that you can't center horizontally with `margin auto` unless you give specific `width` and element is `block` element, `disc style` of li elements mysteriously disappear if its display value is changed to anything from its default `list-item`, in css there is no way to tell block element to fit to its content yet + floating elements to not wrap into next line without setting width on parent + set language in css + content attribute ignore spaces + why i hate css

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Remove the floats and change the `inline-block` attributes to `li` elements. Like this:

```
.wrapper {
    text-align: center;
}
.price_carousel .list {
    padding-left: 1em;
    display:block;
    margin: 0;
}
.price_carousel .list li {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
    list-style-position: inside;
    list-style-type: disc;
    margin-right: 1em;
    text-align: left;
    white-space: nowrap;
}
```

I have added a `white-space: nowrap;` declaration to `li` elements to they never break inside, but you can take it down (I usually take it down myself, but depends on you).

But if you want the `UL` to never break (so the `LI` will always be in the same line), just add this `white-space: nowrap;` declaration to the `UL`

[See fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/f5d36ae5/)

---

**EDIT TO INCLUDE BULLETS:**
`inline-block` elements don't display `list-style-type`, thus the options to include bullets in your case are as follows:

**a) to use float:left;**

```
.price_carousel .list li {
    float:left;
    vertical-align: middle;
    list-style-position: outside;
    list-style-type: disc;
    margin-right: 1em;
    text-align: left;
    white-space: nowrap;
}
```

**b) to use a background-image as bullet**

```
.price_carousel .list li {
    display:inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
    list-style-position: outside;
    list-style-type: disc;
    margin-right: 1em;
    text-align: left;
    white-space: nowrap; padding-left:30px; background:url('http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/e/ef/Bullet_go.png') no-repeat center left;
}
```

**c) to include a span in your HTML markup**

HTML goes like this:

```
    <ul class="list">
        <li><span class="bull">TEXT TEXT</span>
        </li>
        <li><span class="bull">TEXT TEXT</span>
        </li>
        <li><span class="bull">TEXT TEXT</span>
        </li>
    </ul>
```

and CSS like this:

```
.price_carousel .list li {
    display:inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
    list-style-position: outside;
    list-style-type: disc;
    margin-right: 1em;
    text-align: left;
    white-space: nowrap;
    padding-left:30px;
}
.bull {
    display:list-item
}
```

Comment: ah, if you want bullets, then it's different, you have to make changes since inline-block doesn't display list-style-type (and I didn't consider it since it's not common to have a nav with bullets). See answer edit for those changes

Answer (score 2):

In Chrome it renders correctly and they do all display on the same line if you make the window larger.. due to the length of the line and the fact that you've added a margin on the left, there's no room for them to remain on the same line unless you make the window large enough for them to do so.

[image]

I see now that in Firefox it does break to two lines.. and my first assumption is it's related to this style that your adding:

```
list-style-position: inside;
```

[image]

If you remove that, then it renders correctly.

[image]

It appears as though Firefox may have some issues with list-style-position.  Here's a issue that I found on Bugzilla with a similar issue:    https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=36854

Comment: Did a little more looking into it, adjusted my answer with the details for you.